# Filtering a Pandas Dataframe with a boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I drop all dataframe rows  that don't match a pair of conditions.

I did this:

```
df = df[ ! ((df['FVID'] == 0) & (df['vstDelta'] == 0)) ]
```

but that was a syntax error.  Hopefully it illustrates what I want to do, which is to drop all records containing these 2 conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use '~' instead of ! to get the negation of the condition.

```
df = df[~((df['FVID'] == 0) & (df['vstDelta'] == 0))]
```

Comment: I had the further complexity that 'vstDelta' was a timedelta64 object, so a direct comparion to 0 was invalid.    Here is what I did:                      `import datetime`   
`zeroelapse = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()  `
`df = df[~((df['FVIDdiff'] == 0) & (df['vstDelta'] == zeroelapse))] `